# Missing decades in LogLinearplot

Tags: plotting, scripting, logarithmic-scale

I wanted to display all the decades (from 1 to 10^8 like 1 ,10, 10^2, 10^3 etc) in LogLinearPlot and also tried the solution of [why-is-listlogplot-skipping-entire-decades](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48367/why-is-listlogplot-skipping-entire-decades).

And my code is something like this:

```
LogLinearPlot[Vnpre[freq], {freq, 1, 10^8}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.004]}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["freq", Medium],Style["Vnpre[V^2/Hz]", Medium]}, 
 Axes -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thin, Italic] , 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> {Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]}, {i, 0, 10}], Automatic, None, None}]
```

And plot is like this:

[image]

Here, I am not able to see the all decades and also 10^3 is displayed as 1000. Can somebody please help me to correct this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Try the option `FrameTicks`as follows:

```
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Table[{10^i, 
         Style[Superscript[10, i], 12, Italic, Blue] },
 {i, 0, 10}],  None}}
```

Have fun!

**Edit**:

To address your question of how to remove the decimal points of ticks along the y axis. Instead of the `Automatic` you might insert this line:

```
Table[{i*10^-10, 
  ToString[i] <> 
   "\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-10\)]\)"}, {i, 1, 5}]
```

You may also play with the style:

```
Table[{i*10^-10, 
  Style[ ToString[i] <> 
    "\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-10\)]\)", 12, Blue]}, {i,
   1, 5}]
```

Try this altogether:

```
freq = Exp[x];
LogLinearPlot[
 5*10^-10 (Tanh[(freq - 1000)/5000] + 1)/2, {freq, 1, 10^8}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.004]}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["freq", Medium], 
   Style["Vnpre[V^2/Hz]", Medium]}, Axes -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thin, Italic], GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{i*10^-10, 
      ToString[i] <> 
       "\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-10\)]\)"}, {i, 1, 5}],
     None}, {Table[{10^i, 
      Style[Superscript[10, i], 12, Italic, Blue]}, {i, 0, 10}], 
    None}}]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it works... But I have small problem as you can see on the y axis , I get decimal point after the number and now after updating the code with your solution I get 10.^1 ,10.^2 in x axis also... Why is that decimal point after 10?

Comment: I propose that instead of Automatic you put there `{{1*10^-10, 
  Style["1\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-10\)]\)", Blue, 
   12]}, {2*10^-10, 
  Style["2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-10\)]\)", Blue, 
   12]},...}` just written by hand. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I have many graphs which are generated after evaluating some function  and hence I will not be knowing the range of y axis. Is there any generic way of doing this without getting a decimal point or is there any settings in mathematica application that I have to change?

Comment: I also observed that normal function such as: `a = 1;b = 2;c = a + b` give 3. as the answer (decimal point after number). I think the problem is not from the Plot and its in complete code's number format. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The decimal point is the attribute of a Real number. Generally, if you define a = 1;b = 2; then c = a + b will give the Integer 3 That is, without any decimal point. In your case, most probably you have previously assigned one of these variables to a real number during the actual session, and Mma remembered it. It will be forgotten after clearing: `Clear[a,b,c];` or after restarting Mma. Decimal points in your plot most probably originate from the values of the function if those are real. I do not know, if it is the case, since you did not post it.  Please look at the edit to my answer.